# Everything is wrong when I modified standard UITabBar application

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I created "New Project" -> Tab Bar Application. 
Then i changed from @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController to @interface FirstViewController : UINavigationController. 
Then i changed file's owner from UIViewController to UINavigationController in xib file.
Then i updated view. But i don't see any label on the screen. Why? (i have some labels on xib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you subclassing UINavigationController and what are you trying to accomplish? UINavigationController does not display a view of it's own, just the navigation bar over some other view controller's view. In addition UINavigationController was not designed to be subclasses, hence the "This class is not intended for subclassing." warning in its class reference.

If you want to display your view controller as part of a navigation stack you should create an instance of UINavigationController, set that navigation controller as the view controller for one of your tabs, and then push an instance of your FirstViewController onto the UINavigationController.